# Bootstrap stacked rows not working in responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm designing a website on HTML5, CSS3 and Bootstrap.

I'm having trouble setting up a stacked row-column layout. On the web, it looks perfect as I want, something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbMmT.png

The problem is that when going into responsive mode, the top row seen on that pic is show bad, as it does not show all the "cells" of the grid. Also, the Footer is stacked over that row instead of under it. Check this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/45KuC.png

The snippet code:

```css
/* HOME INFO
-------------------------------------------------- */

.row-home-info {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #586f56;
    padding: 0 !important;
}



.row-home-info .col-md-6 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.row-home-info .home-como-llegar {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffff00;
    background-image: url('../img/como-llegar.jpg');
    background-position: center;
}

.row-home-info .home-como-llegar .cover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
}

.row-home-info .home-como-llegar .cover a {
    margin-top: 180px;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0087c3;
    padding: 0;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .row {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .row .col-md-6, .row-home-info .home-col-contacto .row .col-md-3 {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.row-home-info .home-col-contacto a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .newsletter {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/bg-1.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .twitter {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/bg-2.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .facebook {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/bg-3.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .youtube {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/bg-4.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .instagram {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/bg-5.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .contacto {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/bg-6.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .youtube a {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/YouTube.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(0,135,195, 0.8);
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .instagram a {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/Instagram.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(0,90,130, 0.8);
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .twitter a {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/Twitter.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(0,135,195, 0.8);
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .facebook a {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/FB.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(0,90,130, 0.8);
}

.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .contacto a {
    background-image: url("../img/home-socials/contact.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(0, 50, 70, 0.8);
}


/* FOOTER
 *---------------------------------------------*/

.footer {
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #222222;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    font-family: 'MetaPro', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


.footer h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.footer ul {
    width: 80%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.footer li {
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #555555;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row row-home-info">
  <div class="col-md-6 home-como-llegar">
   <div class="cover"><p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Cómo llegar</a></p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 home-col-contacto container-fluid">
   <div class="row" style="height: 50%">
    <div class="col-md-6 newsletter"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/xxxxxx" target="_blank"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 facebook"><a href="http://facebook.com/xxxxx" target="_blank"></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" style="height: 50%">
    <div class="col-md-3 youtube"><a href="http://youtube.com/xxxxxxxx" target="_blank"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 instagram"><a href="http://instagram.com/xxxxx/" target="_blank"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 contacto"><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></div>

   </div>


  </div>

 </div>
</section>
<section class="footer container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Noticias</li>
                <li>Escuela</li>
                <li>Torneos</li>
                <li>Tarifas</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Sobre nosotros</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>El campo</li>
                <li>El equipo</li>
                <li>Contacto</li>
                <li>Pxxxxo</li>
                <li>Laxxxxxxl</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Donde estamos</h4>
            <p>Carretera xxxxxxxxxxx</p>
            <p>Tfno: agasgasgasgasg</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Conecta con nosotros</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>Twitter</li>
                <li>Facebook</li>
                <li>Youtube</li>
                <li>Instagram</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>



</section>
```

Now the actual question, any help on thow to fix this? I know It has same to with with the fixed height on the main rows but I have tried to use min-height and so on an isn't working neither. Maybe is something so easy to do and I'm stuck, but after a week of research and try-error I cannot find the solution.

Hope someone have a light on this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you want to override the fixed height on main rows in a media query? Do you need these heights in mobile versions?

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
   .row-home-info {
     height:auto;      
   }

  .home-col-contacto > .row {
    height:auto !important;      
   }

}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gL31rLp6/5/)

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem. I had already tried that but I was missing something.

I had to add fixed height to .row-home-info .home-col-contacto a setting it to 150px, as I don't have content inside the a (They are just blocks with a background image)

Finally I had:

`.row-home-info .home-col-contacto a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px !important;
}`

And:

`.row-home-info .home-col-contacto .newsletter {
    background: [...];
    height: 150px !important;
}`

Again, thanks for the answer @GL.awog